# How do I get request parameters when using fragment AND query with drupal_goto

Tags: http-request

I was successful in using fragment with drupal_goto, but when I use it AND query, I am not able to get the request parameters using $_GET from the query.

I can see the request parameters in the URL, but it returns NULL.  The URL is constructed as http://mydrupalsite/?code=success#overlay=admin/vendor/auth-stripe.

I am attempting to use $_GET['code'] to get the parameter.  I also tried $_REQUEST

Comment: If that's literally what you're doing (using `$_GET['code']` on a page with exactly that URL), and it's not working, your version of PHP is broken, or you have something stripping out the `$_GET` var before it's available to you. Using Symfony/Laravel/etc? They all do that

Comment: I think you have some other issue. I tried `$_REQUEST['code']` on my site and it's getting correct value.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're trying to access the $_GET from the *page that's loaded in the overlay* (admin/vendor/auth-stripe).  If that's the case, then you've constructed the url wrong.  It should be:
http://mydrupalsite/#overlay=admin/vendor/auth-stripe%3fcode%3dsuccess

That said: where are you actually constructing this URL?  If you're doing it properly, all of that should be taken care of for you automatically.